# Does nginx use "deferred" as the default for the listen directive?

Tags: 11.10, nginx

Many [sites](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/wiki/nginx.conf) recommend using 'deferred' with the listen directive for nginx. Is this necessary on the Ubuntu installation or is "listen 80" sufficient with 'deferred' on by default?

```
listen 80 default deferred; # for Linux
```

Comment: I would check the `nginx` wiki: wiki.nginx.org

Comment: The nginx wiki doesn't say what the default is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deferred` is not enabled by default on Ubuntu, there is no patch that enables it by default.

Below is my attempt to get an understanding of what the option does.

From the reference at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#listen:

> deferred -- indicates to use that postponed `accept(2)` on Linux with the aid of option `TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT`

Right, it refers to the manual page [`accept`, section 2 - System calls (functions provided by the kernel)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man2/accept.2.html). Unfortunately I couldn't find any information in that manual page about the effect of it, so I started digging in the source code (`apt-get source nginx`).

The option is enabled in `nginx-0.8.54/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c:3534`. If `deffered accept` is not supported, you should get an error message on startup:

> the deferred accept is not supported on this platform, ignored

At this point I stopped searching further. It wouldn't make sense if `deferred` is enabled by default in nginx if it cannot be disabled.